# onblur function could not run in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my code has add or remove table row dynamically. Im trying to get auto field calculation. The default first row working well, but the dynamically created rows are does not work. Please help, why onblur function does not run at the newly created table rows?

Comment: *hint: delegated event handler*

Comment: We can't help you without seeing what you've got and what you've tried. Post some code, right now this question is unclear.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/